# watir throws JavascriptError when using parent method to locate element

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Take Github for example, code like these:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

b.goto "https://github.com/about"
puts b.div(:class => "column one-half").present?
puts b.div(:class => "column one-half").parent.text
```

Got these output:

```
[remote server] https://github.com/about line 68 > Function:17:in `H': a is undefined (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)
    from [remote server] https://github.com/about line 68 > Function:17:in `anonymous/</<'
    from [remote server] https://github.com/about line 68 > Function:14:in `anonymous/<'
    from [remote server] https://github.com/about line 68 > Function:14:in `anonymous'
    from [remote server] https://github.com/about:68:in `handleEvaluateEvent'
    from my_path/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
    from my_path/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
    from my_path/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
    from my_path/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
    from my_path/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
    from my_path/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from my_path/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:640:in `raw_execute'
    from my_path/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:618:in `execute'
    from my_path/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:339:in `executeScript'
    from my_path/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:193:in `execute_script'
    from my_path/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/atoms.rb:20:in `execute_atom'
    from my_path/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:373:in `parent'
    from t.rb:9:in `<main>'
true
```

Try other sites, got the same result, anyone know why? Thanks

Comment: I am using Firefox 35.0, and work fine in Chrome 39

Comment: This is likely an issue with Firefox 35.0. There is another Javascript error bug already logged - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8390. You can either downgrade Firefox or wait until the issue is addressed in Selenium-Webdriver.

Comment: Yes, try Firefox 34, work fine again. Thank Justin